# Linux- Removing from specific line number to specific line number

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to remove contents from line number 23 to line number 69 in file file.txt. Is there any command I can use to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has been asked many times, good to see somebody searched for a duplicate instead of posting a duplicate answer :)

Comment: I think @triplee was trying to earn `Deduplicator` badge :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` with `d` command and inline editing option:

```
sed -i.bak '23,69d' file
```